# How to set command line parameters for "run without debugging"?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, settings, command-line-arguments

I'm working on a console application with a lot of command line argument. I can set them for debug in project properties, but couldn't find the way to do so for case "start without debugging". Is there any solution to this in visual studio 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) to achieve it, like :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            args = new[] { "A" };
#endif

            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
        }
```